# How to use (Get|Set)KeyboardState() to modify the keyboard state when using PostMessage()?

Tags: c++, winapi

I read that when the `TranslateMessage()` API is called, it 'checks' your current keyboard state, so if you want to really 'simulate' a key input, you need to also modify the thread's keyboard state.

I'm trying to understand what `|= 0x80` means, is it '*the key is down*'?

```cpp
DWORD current_thread_id = GetCurrentThreadId();
DWORD thread_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);

AttachThreadInput(current_thread_id, thread_id , true);

BYTE KeybState[256] = { '\0' };

GetKeyboardState((PBYTE)&KeybState);

KeybState[...] |= 0x80;

SetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&KeybState);

SetFocus(hWnd);

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, ..., ...);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, ..., ...);

AttachThreadInput(current_thread_id, thread_id , false);
```

What value represents when the key is **up**, `KeybState[...] = 0`?

Suppose I'm trying to send `#`, I need to:

```cpp
KeybState[VK_SHIFT] |= 0x80;
SetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&KeybState);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SHIFT, lParam);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, 0x33, lParam); // 0x33 is the vk_code for the  3 key
```

Or, do I also need to use `KeybState[0x33] |= 0x80;`?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: And how linking to this can helps in anything I have asked? I'm tired of seeing people pasting this link.

Comment: According to [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate#return-value), *If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.* For BYTE, It's 0x80.

Comment: As you're getting fatigued by seeing the same link all over again, let's just pull up a few others for relief: [Sharing an input queue takes what used to be asynchronous and makes it synchronous, like focus changes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143), [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043), and ...

Comment: [I warned you: The dangers of attaching input queues](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080801-00/?p=21393). Advice: Once you find yourself in a hole, stop digging.

Comment: @AlexF `"you need to use another API."` what API?

Comment: @Nikolas [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) or [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32)

Comment: `SendInput()` only works with foreground windows, UI Automation has nothing to with sending key input.